# How to write SFTP script without expect?

Tags: bash, shell, ftp, sftp, system-administration

I have this script but it required expect package to work can we have any other way to upload file over SFTP with out expect because our security team not allowed to install expect package over production server.

my SFTP upload code.

```
/usr/bin/expect<<EOD
spawn /usr/bin/sftp -o Port=$PORT master@$HOST
expect "password:"
send "$PASSWORD\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "put $SOURCE_FILE $TARGET_DIR\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "bye\r"
EOD
```

Can some one help me to convert this to without using expect.

our SFTP server work with username password

Answer (score 1):

The OpenSSH `sftp` client does not have a native support for providing a password for automation.

So you have to workaround that somehow:

- fake user input using `expect` or [`sshpass`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/)
- use public key authentication
- use any other (less common) password-less authentication method

Answer (score 0):

A good solution is to use *lftp* command which allows providing password and running sftp commands in only one command line like this:

```
lftp sftp://$HOST -u username,password -e "put $SOURCE_FILE $TARGET_DIR;bye"
```

Comment: If this is not a standard utility, you should provide a link to it.

Comment: Of course: this is a standard Unix utility. It is also available with Cygwin on Windows platform.

Comment: Ok, it's not on my RHEL or OS X boxes and I've never heard of it so thought it was worth mentioning.